# Servers successfully started from gfsh but not connected to the locator

Tags: gemfire, geode, gfsh

I started a geode locator using gfsh and then started four servers using gfsh again but when I use the list members command, I only get the locator and not the servers.

```
gfsh>start locator --name=locate --port=10334
Starting a Geode Locator in C:\Users\Milin\locate...
.
Locator in C:\Users\Milin\locate on DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[10334] as locate is currently online.
Process ID: 1616
Uptime: 3 minutes 31 seconds
Geode Version: 1.11.0
Java Version: 13.0.2
Log File: C:\Users\Milin\locate\locate.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.enable-cluster-configuration=true -Dgemfire.load-cluster-configuration-from-dir=false -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-core-1.11.0.jar;C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-dependencies.jar

Successfully connected to: JMX Manager [host=DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home, port=1099]

Cluster configuration service is up and running.

gfsh>connect --locator=DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[10334]
Already connected to: DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[1099]

gfsh>list members
Member Count : 1

 Name  | Id
------ | -------------------------------------------------------------
locate | 192.168.0.82(locate:1616:locator)<ec><v0>:41000 [Coordinator]

gfsh>start server --name=serverA --server-port=41101
Starting a Geode Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverA...
.
Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverA on 192.168.0.82[41101] as serverA is currently online.
Process ID: 20920
Uptime: 20 minutes 13 seconds
Geode Version: 1.11.0
Java Version: 13.0.2
Log File: C:\Users\Milin\serverA\serverA.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.start-dev-rest-api=false -Dgemfire.use-cluster-configuration=true -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-core-1.11.0.jar;C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-dependencies.jar

gfsh>start server --name=serverB --server-port=41102
Starting a Geode Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverB...
.
Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverB on DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[41102] as serverB is currently online.
Process ID: 8908
Uptime: 20 minutes 17 seconds
Geode Version: 1.11.0
Java Version: 13.0.2
Log File: C:\Users\Milin\serverB\serverB.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.start-dev-rest-api=false -Dgemfire.use-cluster-configuration=true -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-core-1.11.0.jar;C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-dependencies.jar

gfsh>start server --name=serverC --server-port=41103
Starting a Geode Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverC...
.
Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverC on DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[41103] as serverC is currently online.
Process ID: 5940
Uptime: 20 minutes 15 seconds
Geode Version: 1.11.0
Java Version: 13.0.2
Log File: C:\Users\Milin\serverC\serverC.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.start-dev-rest-api=false -Dgemfire.use-cluster-configuration=true -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-core-1.11.0.jar;C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-dependencies.jar

gfsh>start server --name=serverD --server-port=41104
Starting a Geode Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverD...
.
Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverD on DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[41104] as serverD is currently online.
Process ID: 16548
Uptime: 20 minutes 12 seconds
Geode Version: 1.11.0
Java Version: 13.0.2
Log File: C:\Users\Milin\serverD\serverD.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.start-dev-rest-api=false -Dgemfire.use-cluster-configuration=true -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-core-1.11.0.jar;C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-dependencies.jar

gfsh>list members
Member Count : 1

 Name  | Id
------ | -------------------------------------------------------------
locate | 192.168.0.82(locate:1616:locator)<ec><v0>:41000 [Coordinator]
```

I then also tried to start the servers by specifying the locator name (tried both the name and ID) but still the same results

```
gfsh>stop locator --name=locate
Stopping Locator running in C:\Users\Milin\locate on DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[10334] as locate...
Process ID: 1616
Log File: C:\Users\Milin\locate\locate.log
....

No longer connected to DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[1099].

No longer connected to DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[1099].
gfsh>list members
Command 'list members' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
gfsh>start locator --name=locate --port=10334
Starting a Geode Locator in C:\Users\Milin\locate...
..............................
Locator in C:\Users\Milin\locate on DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[10334] as locate is currently online.
Process ID: 20936
Uptime: 19 seconds
Geode Version: 1.11.0
Java Version: 13.0.2
Log File: C:\Users\Milin\locate\locate.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.enable-cluster-configuration=true -Dgemfire.load-cluster-configuration-from-dir=false -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-core-1.11.0.jar;C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-dependencies.jar

Successfully connected to: JMX Manager [host=DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home, port=1099]

Cluster configuration service is up and running.

gfsh>list members
Member Count : 1

 Name  | Id
------ | --------------------------------------------------------------
locate | 192.168.0.82(locate:20936:locator)<ec><v0>:41000 [Coordinator]

gfsh>connect
Already connected to: DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[1099]

gfsh>describe member --name=locate
Name        : locate
Id          : 192.168.0.82(locate:20936:locator)<ec><v0>:41000
Host        : DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home
Regions     :
PID         : 20936
Groups      :
Used Heap   : 259M
Max Heap    : 1988M
Working Dir : C:\Users\Milin\locate
Log file    : C:\Users\Milin\locate\locate.log
Locators    : 192.168.0.82[10334]

gfsh>start server --name=serverA --server-port=41101 --locators=locate
Starting a Geode Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverA...
.
Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverA on 192.168.0.82[41101] as serverA is currently online.
Process ID: 20920
Uptime: 36 minutes 6 seconds
Geode Version: 1.11.0
Java Version: 13.0.2
Log File: C:\Users\Milin\serverA\serverA.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.start-dev-rest-api=false -Dgemfire.use-cluster-configuration=true -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-core-1.11.0.jar;C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-dependencies.jar

gfsh>list members
Member Count : 1

 Name  | Id
------ | --------------------------------------------------------------
locate | 192.168.0.82(locate:20936:locator)<ec><v0>:41000 [Coordinator]

gfsh>start server --name=serverA --server-port=41101 --locators=192.168.0.82[10334]
Starting a Geode Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverA...
.
Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverA on 192.168.0.82[41101] as serverA is currently online.
Process ID: 20920
Uptime: 36 minutes 27 seconds
Geode Version: 1.11.0
Java Version: 13.0.2
Log File: C:\Users\Milin\serverA\serverA.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.start-dev-rest-api=false -Dgemfire.use-cluster-configuration=true -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-core-1.11.0.jar;C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-dependencies.jar

gfsh>list members
Member Count : 1

 Name  | Id
------ | --------------------------------------------------------------
locate | 192.168.0.82(locate:20936:locator)<ec><v0>:41000 [Coordinator]

gfsh>start server --name=serverB --server-port=41102 --locators=192.168.0.82[10334]
Starting a Geode Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverB...
.
Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverB on DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[41102] as serverB is currently online.
Process ID: 8908
Uptime: 36 minutes 42 seconds
Geode Version: 1.11.0
Java Version: 13.0.2
Log File: C:\Users\Milin\serverB\serverB.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.start-dev-rest-api=false -Dgemfire.use-cluster-configuration=true -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-core-1.11.0.jar;C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-dependencies.jar

gfsh>list members
Member Count : 1

 Name  | Id
------ | --------------------------------------------------------------
locate | 192.168.0.82(locate:20936:locator)<ec><v0>:41000 [Coordinator]

gfsh>start server --name=serverC --server-port=41103 --locators=192.168.0.82[10334]
Starting a Geode Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverC...
.
Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverC on DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[41103] as serverC is currently online.
Process ID: 5940
Uptime: 36 minutes 44 seconds
Geode Version: 1.11.0
Java Version: 13.0.2
Log File: C:\Users\Milin\serverC\serverC.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.start-dev-rest-api=false -Dgemfire.use-cluster-configuration=true -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-core-1.11.0.jar;C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-dependencies.jar

gfsh>start server --name=serverD --server-port=41104 --locators=192.168.0.82[10334]
Starting a Geode Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverD...
.
Server in C:\Users\Milin\serverD on DESKTOP-EMRTT29.hitronhub.home[41104] as serverD is currently online.
Process ID: 16548
Uptime: 36 minutes 44 seconds
Geode Version: 1.11.0
Java Version: 13.0.2
Log File: C:\Users\Milin\serverD\serverD.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.start-dev-rest-api=false -Dgemfire.use-cluster-configuration=true -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-core-1.11.0.jar;C:\apache-geode-1.11.0\lib\geode-dependencies.jar
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening. Also, I have never been able to get this start configuration right in one go anytime. Sometimes, the JMX Manager won't connect, sometimes the locator won't start, and it's just that I am working on a project and this consumes a lot of my time and I am not able to give time to the application part (which I am working on in Java).

Feel free to give advice

Answer (score 1):

This should work out of the box just fine, there's something strange going on here... can you please make sure your servers are ***fully stopped*** and that you don't have any zombie processes ***before*** starting the cluster up again?.

I'm just wondering wether the servers were already started prior to starting the locator, basically because the output from the `start server` command states that the servers have been running for some time already...

```
Uptime: 20 minutes 12 seconds

Uptime: 36 minutes 44 seconds
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I'm not sure why that is the case. I am working on a project and I am using this configuration for that. I use the shutdown --include-locators=true command whenever I shut down my system and then use the same configuration the next time I resume my project. So, I think it might have not shut down properly.